# What does BBDD stand for?

Tags: terminology

I was reading an article that said:

> An example of this is that, by choosing the technology stack well, the same language can now be used in all development contexts: Javascript in the desktop client (DOM), in the mobile client (Cordova, React Native), in the server (Node.js) or in the BBDD (MongoDB).

I don't understand what BBDD is, even looking it up comes with a bunch of spanish to english stuff. Do you know hat it stands for?

Comment: https://www.proz.com/kudoz/spanish-to-english/telecommunications/1190604-bbdd.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Spanish, I believe you often repeat a letter in an abbreviation to indicate a plural, as in EE UU for Estados Unidos = USA.

So presumably, BBDD is the plural of BD = `bases de datos` or in English DB = databases.

Incidentally in French you will see the abbreviation BDD = base de données for database.

Comment: Oh sheesh no way. Thanks!